# Read latest content from multiple CSV files and sort-Logic

Tags: sorting, csv, powershell, compare

I need to get a logic for doing one type of sorting/filtering using multiple CSV files. The problem is  I have 2 two CSV files with some investment content in to. The data would like this:

- **File A_11012015_123.csv**(Time stamp appended)

  ```
   TktNo, AcctID, Rate 
    1      1       187
    2      1       145
    7      2       90
  ```
- **File A_12012015_1345.csv**(Timestamp appended)

  ```
   TktNo, AcctID, Rate
    1      2       190
    2      2       187
    3      5        43
  ```

Expected output file content

```
TktNo, AcctID, Rate
 1      2       190
 2      2       187
 3      5       43
 7      2       90
```

Things have tried , not the exact one

```
  $output=@()
  foreach(..)(multple files)
  {
  $output+=Get -Content -path $csv| sort "TktNo: - Unique
   }
   export $output
```

Conditions for the output file

1. Ticket number should be unique and sorted
2. if there is same ticket number in both files the content of the latest file should be added to the output file.

   As this part of migration to power shell and again I am also a beginner, I appreciate if anybody can help me with the implementation.

Comment: Is there _anything_ that you have tried? I know you are trying to wrap your head around this but if you don't show a little more effort I would think the community would be reluctant to help you. What is the format on your time? Is the first example 1:23AM and the second 1:45PM?

Comment: Thanks Matt. the file name is with the datetime format ->mmddyyyy_hhmmss.csv

Comment: Thats good. Your filename examples do not follow that datetime pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes a couple of things that I tried to address in the comments. More description to follow.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object{
    $rawDate = ($_.BaseName -split "_",2)[1]
    $filedate = [datetime]::ParseExact($rawDate,"MMddyyyy_HHmmss",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)
    Import-csv $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value $filedate -PassThru
} | Group-Object tktno | ForEach-Object{
    $_.Group | Sort-Object Date | Select -Last 1
} | Select-Object TktNo,AcctID,Rate | Sort-Object TktNo
```

**Assumptions**

1. All your csv files are in one location like "c:\temp". Add `-recurse` if you need to
2. You say that your date format is "mmddyyyy_hhmmss". The example file times do not coorespond with that. I editing the file names as such to use "MMddyyyy_HHmmss". "File A_11012015_123321.csv" and "File A_12012015_134522.csv"

**Breakdown**

Couple of ways to do this but a simple one that we used here is `Group-Object`. As long as you don't have 100's of these files with 1000's of entries it should do the trick.

Take each file and for every entry append its file data with `Import-csv $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value $filedate -PassThru`. For example you would have:

```
TktNo    AcctID    Rate    Date    
-----    ------    ----    ----    
1        1         187     11/1/2015 12:33:21 PM    
2        1         145     11/1/2015 12:33:21 PM    
7        2         90      11/1/2015 12:33:21 PM
```

We take all of these files and group them together based on `tktno`. Of each group that is created sort them by date property we created earlier and return the entry that is the current one using `Select -Last 1`. Drop the date property and sort the remaining data on `tktno`

As for output you could just append this to the end.

```
} | Select-Object TktNo,AcctID,Rate | Sort-Object TktNo | Export-CSV "C:\somepath.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let me plug in the code and update you.

Comment: Matt- I have tried out the code, but data not get exp. I am getting a 0KB csv file. Please advise

Comment: Are you still having issues @Renji or shall I assume since you marked this as the answer that you got it all figured out? If not I would like to know if you are able to get output on the console.

Comment: Matt , there were few glitches in the code i added. I was able to make it corrected.Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Renji Did you change anything that would be useful to others? If there are errors in my code I would like to fix them. If it was just something pertinent to your situation only then we can leave well enough alone. Glad it worked out either way.

Comment: Thanks Matt.It was just the way i integrated the code snippet you gave into my actual code. Really it works!